# Is there a way to use Elasticsearch copy_to feature with a condition

Tags: elasticsearch, completion

I am implementing Completion Suggester in my application, and here goes my requirement:

I want to use the Completion Suggester only on two type of fields, only my index is like this (because of some other requirements the fields are not indexed as they come, but instead the data is flattened to match this mapping):

```
flatData": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "key": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "key_type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "value_string": {
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": true,
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
```

So basically, it indexes data under this format :

```json
     {
        "key": "idBook",
        "type": long,
        "key_type": "idBook.long",
        "value_string": 67d25bce-39b5-4069-b137-0698286f50a4
    },
    {
        "key": "bookName",
        "type": "string",
        "key_type": "bookName.string",
        "value_string": "A Song Of Ice And Fire"
    },
    {
        "key": "numPages",
        "type": "string",
        "key_type": "numPages.string",
        "value_string": "8000"
    }
```

In my case, I want to add the completion suggester only when the value of the Key is BookName and AuthorName for example, what I thougt to do is to add an _all field where I copy the values of these keys, in order to have somehting like this :

```
"value_string": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "my_all"
        "fielddata": true,
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
"my_all": {
      "type": "completion"
    }
```

Is there a way to copy_to the field my_all only if the value of the key is bookName for Example ?

Answer (score 1):

## Tldr;

No, `copy_to` does not support conditions.
But it does not mean you can not achieve what you want to do.

You should look toward [ingestion pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) which does [support condition](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html#conditionally-run-processor)

## Solution

You start with this doc

```json
{
    "key": "bookName",
    "type": "string",
    "key_type": "bookName.string",
    "value_string": "A Song Of Ice And Fire"
}
```

Create this pipeline

```json
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my-pipeline
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "description": "If 'url.scheme' is 'http', set 'url.insecure' to true",
        "if": "ctx.key == 'bookname'",
        "field": "my_all",
        "value": "{{{value_string}}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You end up with this document

```json
{
    "key": "bookName",
    "type": "string",
    "key_type": "bookName.string",
    "value_string": "A Song Of Ice And Fire",
    "my_all": "A Song Of Ice And Fire"
}
```

Just create the mapping accordingly to have the field `my_all` to be a of type completion and you should be all set.

Comment: Note that it's also possible to create a custom analyzer on the completion field that leverages the [`condition` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-condition-tokenfilter.html), it's more transparent, worth a try

Comment: So you would copy all the data anyway, and then get rid of it according to a custom script ?

Comment: Only the data satisfying the condition would be indexed in the completion field

Comment: Yes absolutely, that was my understanding. Great thinking . Feel free to edit my post or add your own solution.

Comment: Actually, it won't work, because the condition script can only work on tokens of the field being analyzed, and in this case, we need to check another field's token... so no go, your solution is good.